# hide column 2nd column when row above uses rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this table

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>01/09/16</th>
      <th>02/09/16</th>
      <th>03/09/16</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">In</th>
      <th></th>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>James</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td></td>
      <td>Lisa</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It renders like this

[image]

I want to get rid of the blank column of headers.

[image]

I've tried using this css

```
'th:nth-of-type(2) {display: none;}'
```

I got this instead

[image]

The `rowspan` is throwing me off.  I'm willing to use a clever `regex` substitution or `css`.

Comment: Your last row only has one `<th>`, that's why your CSS isn't working. Is there a reason why you can't just delete the column?

Comment: @KodosJohnson this table has many rows. I'm only showing 2. Another function is returning this string. I need to post process it

Comment: Would Javascript/jQuery be OK? I don't think it is possible without Javascript unfortunately. You only tagged your question with HTML and CSS

Comment: Post away and add the tag. I'll choose a non js answer over a js one though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used css `not` selector

```css
th:nth-of-type(2), tbody th:not([rowspan]) {display: none;}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>01/09/16</th>
      <th>02/09/16</th>
      <th>03/09/16</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">In</th>
      <th></th>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>James</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td></td>
      <td>Lisa</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's get weird with it. I think [`:empty` pseudo selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp) just might be what you're looking for. I don't know how different your full table structure is, but this should put you on the right path.

I placed my `css` on two lines for readability. You can combine as you wish.

```css
tr > th:empty:nth-child(2){display: none;}
tr > td:empty:nth-child(2){display: none;}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>01/09/16</th>
      <th>02/09/16</th>
      <th>03/09/16</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">In</th>
      <th></th>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>James</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td></td>
      <td>Lisa</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked very well.  You were right to wonder about the rest of the table.  I had another row span further down that this hiccuped on.  However, I'm grateful to have learned something new and I'll likely play with the `empty` selector more.  It'd be great to give this a few more up-votes people :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with jquery. This locates each `<th>` with a rowspan attribute and hides any immediately proceeding column.

```js
$("table.dataframe").find("th[rowspan]").each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 2;
    $(this).closest("table.dataframe").find('th,td').filter(":nth-child("+index+")").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>01/09/16</th>
      <th>02/09/16</th>
      <th>03/09/16</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">In</th>
      <th></th>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>James</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td></td>
      <td>Lisa</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by giving tds and ths borders then setting the first col border to 0 or none, but you gonna have to omit or set the table border to 0:

```css
     table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table th, td {
          border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        
        table th.no-border {
          border: none;
        }
```

```html
        <table class="dataframe">
          <thead>
            <tr style="text-align: right;">
              <th class="no-border"></th>
              <th></th>
              <th>01/09/16</th>
              <th>02/09/16</th>
              <th>03/09/16</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th rowspan="2" valign="top">In</th>
              <th></th>
              <td>Jack</td>
              <td>Jack</td>
              <td>James</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <td></td>
              <td>Lisa</td>
              <td>Jack</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

is this table data dynamic?
assuming this table is fixed javascript way would be like this

it checks if your second column is blank then remove then second element of each table row

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
    var check = x[1].innerHTML;

    if(check == "") {
        var blk_0 = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
        var blk_1 = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1];
        var blk_2 = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[2];
        blk_0.removeChild(blk_0.childNodes[3]);
        blk_1.removeChild(blk_1.childNodes[3]);
        blk_2.removeChild(blk_2.childNodes[1]);
    }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3erhzcta/